# Should I get more Awesome?

Tags: marvel-heroes

I've just unlocked Deadpool and started playing him. Quickly, I realized that his Awesome...resource(I guess) doesn't go down and that some skills give different boosts based on your Awesome level.

Is it useful to build into having more awesome points based on those stat boosts or should I just build towards having more of the base stats like Critical Hit rate or Brutal Hit rate for a serious damage-dealing hero?